# How to fetch DBPROPERTIES, S3Location and comment set while creating database in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

As provided in AWS athena documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-database.html

We can specify DBPROPERTIES, S3Location and comment while creating Athena database as

```
  CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) [IF NOT EXISTS] database_name
  [COMMENT 'database_comment']
  [LOCATION 'S3_loc']
  [WITH DBPROPERTIES ('property_name' = 'property_value') [, ...]]
```

For example:

```
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS clickstreams
  COMMENT 'Site Foo clickstream data aggregates'
  LOCATION 's3://myS3location/clickstreams/'
  WITH DBPROPERTIES ('creator'='Jane D.', 'Dept.'='Marketing analytics');
```

But once the properties are set. How can I fetch the properties back using Query.

Let say, I want to fetch creator name from the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fetch AWS Athena Database properties in Json format using following code of Glue data catalog.

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabaseRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabaseResult;

public class Glue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("*api*","*key*");
        AWSGlue glue = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("*bucket_region*")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();
        GetDatabaseRequest req = new GetDatabaseRequest();
        req.setName("*database_name*");
        GetDatabaseResult result = glue.getDatabase(req);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Also, following permissions are required for user

1. AWSGlueServiceRole
2. AmazonS3FullAccess

Answer (score 1):

You can get these using the Glue Data Catalog [`GetDatabase` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-databases.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-databases-GetDatabase).

Databases and tables in Athena are stored in the Glue Data Catalog. When you run DDL statements in Athena it translates these into Glue API calls. Not all operations you can do in Glue are available in Athena, because of historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Theo. But is it possible to use Glue data catalog using Java? Looks like it only supports Scala and Python.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990462/can-we-use-java-for-etl-in-aws-glue

Comment: You interact with the Glue Data Catalog API using the AWS SDK. The references you've seen to Scala and Python are for Glue ETL, which is a managed Spark runtime. Glue has many parts, which can be confusing.